# Trying to find out the cost of a square meter

Tags: square-numbers

I am looking for the prices of a land

And I would like to find out how much is a square meter cost if a 391,000 square meter is Equal to 6.5bil

Answer (score 0):

You may just divide 6.5 billions by 391´000 square meters, i.e.

$$\frac{6´500´000´000\ $}{391´000\ \text{m}^2}=16624 \text{ dollars per square meter}$$

(assuming you mean 6.5 billion dollars by "6.5bil")

Answer (score 0):

Let x is the price per square meter.

Then x * 391,000 = 6.5bil

x = $\frac{6.5\text{bil}}{391,000}$

You can change bil into accordance with the 391,000 type. I mean whether it dollars, euros.

Hope you can solve it further.